# Alpha for each layer

Tags: adobe-photoshop, script

How can I set a script  that applies an alpha channel for each layer in the PSD file? An action makes it for one layer only. I`d like to have an ability to automate it for a bunch of layers.

Comment: What? Alpha is automatic if the background is transparent... Control+Shift+E = merge all (visible) layers. What are you asking?

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is a Photoshop Script instead which can allow you to apply an action to layers. Since you have an already recorded action you could use [xtools to convert the action to a script](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ps-scripts/files/xtools/). You might also have a look at [their forums](http://ps-scripts.com/bb/index.php) to see if your need has already been addressed with somebody elses' script.